# Communicating VM with a Router

Tags: networking, routing, vmware-esxi

I have a VM with 2 Virtual NIC, the first NIC has been assigned IP for communication in our ring network the second NIC has been assigned VLAN 809 and has 
IP: 172.32.17.10/16 . The server with this VM has been connected as shown in diagram below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQtUE.jpg

I am unable to ping the router , but when I connect my cables of server on Distribution switch with the ports trunked I am able to ping the router. What should I do so my VM can ping the router when the connections are as shown in the diagram above?

I have already created VLAN 809 in all switches and I don’t want the connection from my Distribution Switch to router to be on Access port with a single VLAN as I have other traffic being passed on the same port through VLAN 1 (Basically I have kept it trunked as shown in Diagram).

Comment: Show us how your VSS/VDS is setup on the vSphere side please

Comment: Yupp, need to see the vSphere site of the configuration before we can help you!